# Error Telegram id and hash "Incorrect app name&#33"

Tags: api, client, telegram

I know it sounds stupid but I am facing an issue obtaining api_id and api_hash as per https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id  . When clicking on "Create Application" I am receiving the error: "Incorrect app name!". What am I missing?
Thank you in advance

Comment: To clarify, I do not know what "App title:" and "Short title:" should I insert from the page https://my.telegram.org/apps in order not to have errors. Is there any mandatory character or minimum lenght name to respect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was pretty easy, it seems it accepts only alphanumeric characters. No underscores.

Comment: It's wildly confusing that the „App Title“ in the error message does NOT refer to the only input field labelled „App Title“. Instead it's referring to the input field labelled „Short name“. That drove me quite some nuts.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
App title: chatbot
Short name: conversational chat bot
```

Open in the website in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In the "App title:" you must introduce only letters more than 5
In the "Short name:" you must introduce only numbers more than 5

Example:

```
App title: firstApp 
Short name: 12345
```